# Change mysql server timzone through my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to change my `MySQL` server time zone, How can set this new timezone in `my.cnf`?

for instance I want to set it to `Brazil/East`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set defualt time zone under my.cnf

```
default-time-zone='timezone'
```

For More
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: When I set this to `my.cnf` and tried to restart my server, I got this message => `The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/srv.xyz.com.pid)` on starting mysql server! any ideas?

Comment: there would be some error!. please check error log of mysql